# dlopen()/dlsym() on the main executable: how portable is it?

Tags: unix, dll, dlopen

I'm building a compiler and a virtual machine for executing my byte code. The language allows to bind external C functions, which may be defined in some external shared object, as well as the main compiler/VM binary (some essential language built-ins).

I know I can dynamically bind symbols within the main executable with dlopen(NULL, ...), however NOT after I run `strip` on the binary. I have the following questions then:

1. Is there a way to do this on a strip'ed binary?
2. How portable is this feature across UNIX systems in general?
3. Is it possible to do the same trick on Windows somehow?
4. Any alternatives ways of binding dynamically within the main executable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use `strip -d` instead to only strip debug symbols.
2. The `dlopen(3)` man page says:

   > ```
   > CONFORMING TO
   >        POSIX.1-2001 describes dlclose(), dlerror(), dlopen(), and dlsym().
   > ```

   So, very portable across *nix.
3. Windows uses [`LoadLibrary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(VS.85).aspx) and [`GetProcAddress()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(VS.85).aspx) instead.
4. No.

Comment: Ignacio, thanks. Looks like you meant `strip -s symbols-file binary`, which would work OK, except on Darwin it says: "strip: removing global symbols from a final linked no longer supported.  Use -exported_symbols_list at link time when building: ..." But anyway, it's a good starting point for me. Also, I fear Windows will have some surprises as usual, but we'll see...

Comment: Sorry, because I was testing this on OS X there was a little confusion with options. The only portable way to run strip is `strip -Sx ...`, also gcc should be run with `-rdynamic` on Linux (not needed on Darwin though). A bit messy but manageable I guess.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: 4. What about a look-up table with function pointers?

Comment: @user877329: The function pointers would still need to be relocated.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I have passed an interface pointer (That is the vtable) to a client dll on Windows with success.